# Is it possible to obfuscate java code and then building an APK file from those java files?

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, code-access-security

I am building an android app and i want to secure its source code. I am building it by using Java. As i have gone through some answers here which is related to obfuscation of java code and protecting it from reverse engineering. So is it also possible in android development. If yes then how?
And if it is not possible then how can we protect apk file from reverse engineering.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at ProGuard :
[Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link and help.